# Shadows messed up, they wont go away no matter how bright of a light I add

Tags: modeling

[image]

So yeah like the title says I have a light directly over that shadow in the left corner. No matter what light I put or how bright I make it that shadow stays. It lights up the rest of the scene but that shadows will not go away. I'm new to blender so sorry if this is something that is obvious.

Comment: Maybe you have a hidden mesh we don't know about? It's hard to guess with the current information.

Comment: Did you disable light or object shadows? Lift the light up a bit too.

Comment: In reply to the first comment, all my meshes are visible. I'm wondering if its a problem with the books because they are each an object I was not able to join them because if I joined them then they would all be the same color.  Then in reply to the second comment, I haven't disabled any of that. And I've moved the light everywhere changed the type of lighting how bright it is and the scene looks exactly the same anyway I do it :/.

Comment: So I have no idea what was going on with this scene. Luckily I made all the assets into their own files so I just started the scene over from a new file and the lighting is fixed. So I guess I changed one setting in the screenshot above that made it look weird with the shadows but I have no idea what it was.